# Experimental bond lengths and binding energies of diatomic molecules

Tags: bond, intermolecular-forces, databases

Is it possible to find the experimental values of the *bond length* and the *binding energy* of the diatomic molecules $\text H_2$, $\text{Be}_2$, and $\text{Ar}_2$ in one source?

I found a lot of chemistry handbooks and databases, but non of the provided both, the bond length and the binding energy for all three molecules.

I guess the experienced chemists know some good sources?

Comment: IMHO, Be2 and Ar2 hardly deserve to be called _molecules_.

Comment: Yes, could be right, because the binding energy of Ar2 is about -12 meV and of Be2 about -100 meV. Meybe this is the reason why I can not find data...

Comment: Might not have all the information you are looking for, but if it has an experimental (or computational) bond length, it will probably be here: https://cccbdb.nist.gov/diatomicexpbondx.asp. Diargon is no dice, but they actually do have a value for diberylium.